# htaccess rewriting subdomain to a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite my main domain to a path and if no query is appended then to a different path. I have a wildcard C name in place to support subdomains.

www.xxx.com => works normally

abc.xxx.com => point to a folder

abc.xxx.com/abc-xyz => point to www.xxx.com and should work normally

This is what i have right now :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
    RewriteRule ^$ portfolio/index.php?pageDetailId=%1 [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?pageDetailId=%1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

As we can see, i need that abc as variable in abc.example.com/abc-xyz. Please reply with doubts with any, i tried many ways its not working. This same htaccess works on 1 domain smoothly but when i created a new domain its not working on that. Thanks.

NOTE: It works on httpd but not on apache2

Comment: What is the URL that is not working and how that should it be handled ?

Comment: abc.example.com is not pointing to 'portfolio/index.php' that means       'RewriteRule ^$ portfolio/index.php?pageDetailId=%1 [NC,L]' is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([\w-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ portfolio/index.php?pageDetailId=%1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([\w-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?pageDetailId=%1&/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Its not working. I removed all rules and just kept :        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([\w-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ portfolio/index.php?pageDetailId=%1 [NC,L]                                        The internal path didn't change to 'portfolio/' it was still pointing to main index.

Comment: A1. yes i entered `http://abc.example.com in browser it opens     http://abc.example.com/index.php?pageDetailId=%1`. This same rules opens correctly in httpd (old server) but doesnt work on apache2(new server). A2. when i enter `http://abc.example.com/portfolio/index.php?pageDetailId=abc` in browser it opens too.

Comment: Oh it is definitely enabled, it does give 500 Internal server error if i do that. And 1 interesting thing is if I use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ portfolio/index.php?pageDetailId=%1 [NC,L]` then it works perfectly well but when I use `RewriteRule ^$ portfolio/index.php?pageDetailId=%1 [NC,L]` it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111045/discussion-between-jinendra-khobare-and-anubhava).